# Haskell comparing IO UTCTime

Tags: haskell

I am completely new to Haskell and I can't find an answer to this problem. Maybe I was searching for the wrong thing.

I am having problems with a small script that's supposed to take two file paths and a `IO UTCTime` timestamp. The idea is to check every 5 seconds whether the directory was modified or not. I am leaving out the details of the script for simplicity's sake. It boils down to:

```
import Data.List
import Control.Monad
import Control.Concurrent
import System.Directory
import Data.Time.Clock

main = doLoop "FilePath" "FilePath" getCurrentTime

doLoop lastPath currentPath lastModified = do
     modified <- getModificationTime currentPath
     if (lastModified /= modified)
       then print "Success"
       else do threadDelay 5000000
               doLoop "FilePath" "FilePath" lastModified
```

I'm getting the compile error:

```
Couldn't match expected type `UTCTime`
with actual type `IO UTCTime`
In the third argument of `doLoop`, namely `getCurrentTime`
```

getCurrentTime is supposed to produce a `IO UTCTime` according to the documentation, just like `getCurrentTime`. What am I missing here?

Comment: If you try to add a type signature to `doLoop` you will see what the problem is. On one hand, your `doLoop` expects its third argument to be a `UTCTime`, but when you call it in `main`, you give it an `IO UTCTime`. Try changing main to: `main = do { currTime <- getCurrentTime; doLoop "FilePath" "FilePath" currTime }` (or just `main = doLoop "FilePath" "FilePath" =<< currTime` if you are so inclined).

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thank you very much! Was it because of the lack of a "do" call that Haskell expected a non-monadic argument instead of IO UTCTime, even though the functions I used can only produce monadic results?

Comment: @Ozan No, it expected a non-`IO` argument because you pass it to `(/=)` along with another non-`IO` thing. Neither whether you use `do` syntax nor whether you produce an `IO` thing in the end is related at all.

Comment: Unrelated to your current error, I don't think that comparison makes a lot of sense. Why would the modification time ever be _exactly equal to the current time_?

Comment: @leftaroundabout I left a huge chunk of the code out.  The current time should never be equal to the modification time of the directory, so the code always runs through then the first time (which also prints a couple of things for me to better understand what the code is doing). At the end, after waiting 5 seconds, it calls _doLoop_ recursively with _modified_, so in the second run of the loop it is really comparing the modification timestamps of the directory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`IO UTCTime` is not the type of a timestamp. It's the type of *an action that can give you a timestamp*. This is a huge difference. It thus doesn't make sense for `doLoop` to accept an `IO UTCTime` as its last argument, what you want is probably

```
doLoop :: FilePath -> FilePath -> UTCTime -> IO ()
```

always write out type signatures like this, to find out where the error is really happening and to document your intent!

What doesn't work then is `doLoop "FilePath" "FilePath" getCurrentTime`, because `getCurrentTime` *is* an action to *obtain* timestamps rather than an actual timestamp. (If it were just a single timestamp, it could hardly be *current* whenever you call it, could it?)

Hence you need to *evaluate* this action to get an actual timestamp which you can then pass to `doLoop`. The easiest way is in a `do` block:

```
main = do
   t <- getCurrentTime
   doLoop "FilePath" "FilePath" t
```

More concisely, you can also Kleisli-compose these two `IO` actions:

```
main = doLoop "FilePath" "FilePath" =<< getCurrentTime
```

...which is actually what that `do` syntax desugars to, anyway.

Comment: I see. I naively expected Haskell to insert the current timestamp as an argument when I call the function like that. Thanks for pointing our my mistake.